# problems in following ros tutorial (make a map and navigate it)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow ros tutorial (make a map and navigate it). However each time I tried to use gazebo and RViz, it crushes. Please guide me how to solve the problem?
Is the problem related to graphics card? My machine is using nvidia driver (NVIDIA Corporation G92 [GeForce 9800 GT] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191992/problems-in-following-ros-tutorial--(make-a-map-and-navigate-it)/) by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on 2014-09-05**:
However I successfully finished the tutorial 'Explore the Gazebo world'.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-05**:
Any error messages or something like that would be very helpful. What crashes? Gazebo or RViz?

**Comment by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on 2014-09-07**:
thanks a lot for your response.
When I tried the following RViz seems trying to start but fails.
$ roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch
I need to restart my computer then.
Why this is happening?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-07**:
Can you run RViz alone? try $ rosrun rviz rviz

**Comment by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on 2014-09-11**:
yes. I can run RViz alone. Also gazebo.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-11**:
Please post the link to your tutorial.

**Comment by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on 2014-09-11**:
Here it is:
http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/hydro/Make%20a%20map%20and%20navigate%20with%20it

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-11**:
Ok try the following: Follow the tutorial till you come to the RViz point. Then start RViz with `$ rosrun rviz rviz` Then you can try adding the plugins by yourself and maybe you find the plugin that makes problems. Add the plugins you see in the picture in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does it crush immediatly?

Check your model files (.stl .urdf .xml), because if they are wrong RViz crashs immediatly and you never get any information about that.
If you downloaded the .stl files from the repositories pay attention that right click with the mouse "save as" will download the html page and not the file

Regards

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on 2014-09-07**:
Yes it crushes immediately. RViz seems trying to start but fails.
I am new to ROS. I am using turtlebot in simulation.
Thanks a lot for your reply.